# Top Bottom span using absolute position not working correctly with line break

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have a div, that div containing a list of span, each span containing 2 spans: top and bottom.

```
<div>
    <span class="text">
        <span class="top">Top 1</span>
        <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 1</span>
    </span>
    <span class="text">
        <span class="top">This is very very very very very very long Top 2</span>
        <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 2</span>
    </span>
    <span class="text">
        <span class="top">Top 3</span>
        <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 3</span>
    </span>
    <span class="text">
        <span class="top">Top 4</span>
        <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 4</span>
    </span>
    <span class="text">
        <span class="top">Top 5</span>
        <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 5</span>
    </span>
    <span class="text">
        <span class="top">Top 6</span>
        <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 6</span>
    </span>
    <span class="text">
        <span class="top">Top 7</span>
        <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 7</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to set the top span above bottom span, and if the top span length is bigger than bottom span, it will be hidden, like this
[image]

Its working with normal relative and absolute css:

```
.text{
  position: relative;
}
.top{
    font-size: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 600;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: -3px;
}
```

But when breaking lines, the top span missing at that point
[image]

I tried to add display: inline-block to .text but the lines is not breaking correctly (it is breaking the line for the whole bottom and I dont want that, I want the line can be broke anywhere for example **This is**, or **This is bottom**)

This is jsfiddle link for more detail https://jsfiddle.net/6qyd397a/3/

---

Updated 15/4 from **Atomkind**:

Adding a span inside .top span would be an option, the .top span is now always shown, but still there is one case that the first letter of bottom span is in second line but the top span is still in the first line

Comment: Try this

```css
.text{
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: @Morta1, unfortunately, that is the same as display: inline-block, that is breaking the line for the whole bottom as well

Comment: How about discarding the `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: @Morta1, I need the overflow:hidden to hide the .top when the text inside is too long. The problem is when breaking the lines, the .bottom is broken to another line but the .top span is not broken, that made .top span hidden

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you want and what the problem is but i tried different things like add `box-sizing: border-box;` and i also played arround with `display: flex;` but it seems like there's not realy a nice solution.

Because of `display: inline;` and the possible line-breaks, here's a problem: If the line breaks BEFORE the first letter is written, the `top: -3px` position is in the above line and could not be shown because of the `overflow: hidden;`.

But why? Well, there are whitespaces (and line-breaks) between your HTML-elements! In detail, the space between `<div class="text">` (with `position: relative;`) and `<div class="top">`. Also the space between end-tag of `.top`  and `<div class="bottom">`!

Just remove these whitesoaces and line-breaks in your HTML-Code.
In this way you make sure, the `.top` element starting-point for positioning is on the exact same place like the first content of `.bottom` and not way before and maybe on another line.
And i suggest using `box-sizing: border-box;` ;-)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text{
  position: relative;
}
.top{
    font-size: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 600;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<br /><br /><br />
<div>
    <span class="text"><span class="top">Top 1</span><span class="bottom">This is Bottom 1</span></span>
    <span class="text"><span class="top">This is very very very very very very long Top 2</span><span class="bottom">This is Bottom 2</span></span>
    <span class="text"><span class="top">Top 3</span><span class="bottom">This is Bottom 3</span></span>
    <span class="text"><span class="top">Top 4</span><span class="bottom">This is Bottom 4.</span></span>
  <span class="text"><span class="top">Top 5</span><span class="bottom">This is Bottom 5</span></span>
  <span class="text"><span class="top">Top 6</span><span class="bottom">This is Bottom 6</span></span>
    <span class="text"><span class="top">Top 7</span><span class="bottom">This is Bottom 7</span></span>
  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8fsn9mzd/

UPDATE 2021-04-15:
Another way is to add a new element inside the `.top` element:
https://jsfiddle.net/xdqzab6p/
In there the TOPs are always shown, but in 1 case in a strange way:
[image: showing the TOP on the old line but breaks BOTTOM into a new...]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text{
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.top{
  font-size: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: -3px;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  background: tomato;
}
.ellips{
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<br /><br /><br />
<div>
    <span class="text">
    <span class="top">
      <span class="ellips">Top 1</span>
    </span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 1</span>
  </span>
    <span class="text">
    <span class="top ellips">This is very very very very very very long Top 2</span>
      <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 2</span>
    </span>
    <span class="text">
    <span class="top">
      <span class="ellips">Top 3</span>
    </span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 3</span>
  </span>
    <span class="text">
    <span class="top">
      <span class="ellips">Top 4</span>
    </span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 4.</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">
      <span class="ellips">Top 5</span>
    </span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 5</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">
      <span class="ellips">Top 6</span>
    </span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 6</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">
      <span class="ellips">Top 7</span>
    </span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 7</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The box-sizing is not working, actually, the problem happens even AFTER the first letter written, if the line breaks between the span, the top will be hidden, for example: "This is bottom 6" in picture above, the line is broken at "This is" but the top span is still not shown

Comment: i know what the problem is and i saw my answer is only working in firefox.. i'll try to fix it for safari and chrome (maybe also testing IE and edge...)

Comment: i updated my answer but this is the only thing i could get for the time. If this is for commenting text or adding info to the text, maybe a marking with :hover tooltip would be easier ;-)

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that seem like the .top can not break into second line, no matter what spaces or no spaces, so maybe display: inline-block is the best thing for now

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe use position fixed for the .top

```
.top{
font-size: 7px;
position: fixed;
font-weight: 600;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
max-width: 100%;
top: 3px;
```

}

Comment: The problem is when breaking the lines, the .bottom is broken to another line but the .top span is not broken, that made .top span hidden, so that even we set the fix width, the issue is still there

Comment: Ok sorry dude I didn't understand that @DatLam

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you break the word the top doesn't show up possible fix for that is given below. Hope it works for you:

**Css:**

```
.text {
  position: relative;
}

.top {
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: -3px;
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">Top 1</span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 1</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">This is very very very very very very long Top 2</span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 2</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">Top 3</span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 3</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">Top 4</span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 4</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">Top 5</span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 5</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">Top 6</span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 6</span>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <span class="top">Top 7</span>
    <span class="bottom">This is Bottom 7</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason why you can't break the `.top` to another line is that it is positioned as absolute. But, even if you could, it would move to a smaller line, meaning that it would not be able to stay on top of the `.bottom`. You need to add:

```
.bottom{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can also add a script to update the `.top` so that it doesn't stay smaller if the window resizes or the `.bottom` text changes and becomes smaller or bigger.

```
<script>
    let allTexts = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
    let allTops = document.querySelectorAll(".text > .top");
    let allBottoms = document.querySelectorAll(".text > .bottom");

    function resize(){
        for (i = 0; i < allTexts.length; i++){
            allTops[i].style.maxWidth = allBottoms[i].offsetWidth;
        }
    }

    setInterval(function(){
        resize();
    }, 300);
</script>
```

The answer is that it is too hard to fix your problem, as there isn't a CSS property to do it.